# R - Running a loop over a few actions

Tags: r, function, loops, while-loop, maps

I've asked a similar question late last year but couldn't find the time to work on that project until now.

So in the code below, I make a map of the bikes available in Paris using live data. The idea I have is to make a loop of this over time (I read that loops take a while to run so I might not have to add a time component to this) and save each map under a different name to see the "flow" of bike availability over a day for example.

Where I'm stuck is that I don't know how to run a loop over this. I've tried "for" I've tried "while" I've tried to put this as a function and then loop it and while I'm sure this is feasible I'm just out of options.

If someone has an idea of how to do this or direct me towards a tutorial I'd be forever grateful.

Thanks!

```
  sta.Paris <- read.csv(url("https://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/velib-disponibilite-en-temps-reel/download/?format=csv&timezone=Europe/Berlin&use_labels_for_header=true"),sep=";")

  sta.Paris1 <- sta.Paris %>% separate(Coordonnées.géographiques,into=c("lat","lon"),sep=",") %>%
    mutate(lat=as.numeric(lat),lon=as.numeric(lon))


  sta.Paris1[15] <- NULL


  sta.Paris2 <- na.omit(sta.Paris1)


  sta.Paris2$velorange = cut(sta.Paris2$Nombre.total.vélos.disponibles,
                             breaks = c(0,5,10,15,20,25,100), right=F,
                             labels = c("Tres peu [0-5)", "Peu [5-10)","Moyen [10-15)","Assez [15-20)","Beaucoup [20-25)", "Enormement [25-100)")
  )


  colorFactor(palette = c("azure2","yellow","orange","red","red4","black"), domain = sta.Paris2$velorange)

  map.velib1 <- leaflet(data = sta.Paris2) %>%
    addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png") %>%
    addCircleMarkers(~ lon,~ lat,
                     color = ~ pal(velorange),
                     popupOptions(T),
                     radius=~ 3 ,stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.7,popup = ~ sprintf("<b> Vélos dispos: %s</b>",as.character(Nombre.total.vélos.disponibles)))

  map.velib1
```

Comment: What about gganimate! That would even give a nice animation of the data: https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html

Comment: Are you trying to loop through a series of values (e.g., timestamps), or do you need to schedule a process to run repeatedly at prespecified times? A `for` loop would work for the former but not for the latter.

Comment: Thanks! gganimate does look cool but I think I'd have the same issue as I'd have to get the data every x minute and that's what I don't know how to do. My idea was to edit a little video on Final Cut when I have all the maps.

And yeah I think the latter.. What do you suggest?